# Using the >, <, and = operators on letter grades

Tags: excel, if-statement, conditional-formatting

I have put in conditional formatting on my seating plan I am setting up, that compares the students current grade with their target grade.

If the current grade is higher than the target - the cell turns green.
`=IF(G4>G5,TRUE, FALSE)`

If the current grade is lower - the cell turns red.
`=IF(G4<G5,TRUE, FALSE)`

If the current grade matches - the cell turns orange.
`=IF(G4=G5,TRUE, FALSE)`

The problem occurs when the current grade contains a - or a + after the grade. e.g Target = C Current = C+

I want to change the formula in the conditional formatting for this so that if it the current grade CONTAINS the grade in the Target grade cell then it turns orange.

Any ideas??

Comment: By which formula you are assigning letters to the marks like : =IF(D2>=80,"A", IF(D2>=75, "B+", IF(D2>=70, "B", IF(D2>=70,"B", IF(D2>=65,"C+", IF(D2>=60, "C","D"))))))

Comment: The grades are not calculated, they are simply entered into the table.

Comment: i'm not sure what examples you need pnuts, other than the example given above.

Comment: if the current grade = C+ and the target grade = C, I want to be able to change the colour of the cell to orange to indicate the child is still on target.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> if the current grade = C+ and the target grade = C, I want to be able to change the colour of the cell to orange to indicate the child is still on target.

Select G4 and try this CF formula rule with orange formatting:

```
=LEFT(G4)=G5
```

Does **not** cater for, say, the target being `C+`.

Comment: Thank you pnuts.  Still didn't work unfortunately :(   The target will only ever be a whole letter, no + or -.

Comment: I would add screenshots of my work but I don't have a high enough rating rate.

Comment: Thank you pnuts.  Your answer and Jean's above have both helped to get this working.  Brilliant!!  I needed to take away the if's from the other conditional formatting rules and then your rule worked. :)

Answer (score 0):

First, get rid of the `IF`; it's useless. If true then true adds no information, only clutter.

```
=IF(G4>G5,TRUE, FALSE)
```

is the exact same thing as

```
=G4>G5
```

so just use the latter.

Now what you want is to turn your letter grades into numerical values that can be compared using `<`, `>` and `=`. For example,

```
C   1
C+  2
B-  3
B   4
B+  5
A-  6
A   7
```

To accomplish this, you can use the `MATCH` function and a literal array. So instead of just `G4` you would have:

```
MATCH(G4,{"C";"C+";"B-";"B";"B+";"A-";"A"},0)
```

So to check whether `G4>G5` you would use

```
=MATCH(G4,{"C";"C+";"B-";"B";"B+";"A-";"A"},0)>MATCH(G5,{"C";"C+";"B-";"B";"B+";"A-";"A"},0)
```

Make sure all the letter grades are there **in ascending order** i.e. worst grade first, best grade last, so that better grades get a higher numerical value (higher index in the array) than worse ones.

Instead of having the list of letter grades hardcoded in the formula, it would likely be better to write the array in a range of cells somewhere in your workbook, name that range e.g. `LetterGrades`, and refer to that in the function:

```
=MATCH(G4,LetterGrades,0)>MATCH(G5,LetterGrades,0)
```

So your conditional formatting input would look like this:

[image]

Same principle goes for `G4<G5` and `G4=G5`.

Example result:

[image]

Comment: Jean-Francois Corbett -  don't I need to do this though, when the formula is going into the conditional formatting "use a formula" option?

Comment: Why ask me when you can try it and convince yourself?

Comment: [For green.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29165856/using-the-and-operators-on-letter-grades) See the screenshot I added.

Comment: ok thank you.  I will give this a go later as will take a bit of editing on my sheet.  Thankyou

Comment: I have read the comment.  I was being courteous.  Getting rid of the ifs in my other conditions as you mentioned and pnuts suggestion below have worked.  I have added this comment so that you can see although I have not accepted your answer, I have used part of it and I appreciate the time.  thank you

Comment: @pnuts: Same thing but `=` instead of `>`. I just reread the question and don't get why this wouldn't address the question, as you intimated in your comment to your own answer. Green if grade is higher (`>` in formula) than target, red if lower (`<`), and orange if equal (`=`).

Comment: Wha... Dammit, you may be right. Arh, what a waste of time that was. I thought this was a great solution, but question too unclear. Honestly, I still don't understand the requirement. Really frustrating.